# Using Codeigniter to generate TCPDF Table with MultiCell height/cell adjustment

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I'm tring to generate a PDF report with TCPDF where I'm fetching data from database and creating PDF TABLE. But in particular cell where I'm using `MultiCell` , details are stacked at one area, I'm using MultiCell for thi Cell. Below is my Output file.[image: Output File]

Below is my Controller Code

```
$slno=0;
        $pdf->cell(1);
        $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B');
        $pdf->Cell(8, 10, 'SL', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(24, 10, 'Applied Date', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(22, 10, 'Start Date', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(22, 10, 'End Date', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->MultiCell(12, 10, 'No. of Days', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Reason', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Category', 'LTRB', 0, 'C', FALSE);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Status', 'LTRB', 1, 'C', FALSE);

            foreach($result->result() as $key){

                $pdf->cell(1);
                $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
                $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '');
                $pdf->Cell(8, 10, ++$slno, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(24, 10, $key->application_date, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(22, 10, $key->start_date, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(22, 10, $key->end_date, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(12, 10, $key->number_of_days, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->MultiCell(40, 10, $key->reason, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $key->leave_type, 'LBR', 0, 'C', FALSE);
                $pdf->Cell(20, 10, $key->status, 'LBR', 1, 'C', FALSE);
            }
```

I tried all other ways through net but I'm not satisfied with result. Is there any other way to make that table fit to look? Little Help please...

Answer (score 1):

It's better you use `writeHTML` which create table using html. Because I have try solution to adjust the multicell, and the problem is there is no fix solution for manually by adjust maxmimum length of the character allowed per line. every character not have same width.
you can view example at http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

**ADDITIONAL :**

For example you ask of using this method to fetch data from db
First you need declare the variable for the header of your table

```
$html = '<table>
           <tr>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
              <th>Column 3</th>
              <th>Column 4</th>
           </tr>';
 foreach($result->result() as $key){
     $html .= '<tr>
                  <td>'.$key->column1.'</td>
                  <td>'.$key->column2.'</td>
                  <td>'.$key->column3.'</td>
                  <td>'.$key->column4.'</td>
               </tr>';
  }
  $html .= '</table>';
```

then you can write out that variable.
That's the simple example of your additional question from the comment.
You can make an improvement, using your HTML skill. BUT remember, TCPDF not fully support of the CSS.
Hope that can help you.

Comment: I'm trying with `writeHTML` now. But how to fetch data from db to table in this concept? any examples will be helpful.

Comment: please check the answer, I updated with the example.

Comment: Got it my friend. Did the same as above. :)

Comment: Do you mean the result is same as before, and does not solve your problem?

Comment: I used HTML for this as suggested.